# Renaming Gradle Project in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle

I have a Gradle-root-project that I would like to rename (I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2) and I can't find an option to do so. With a Java project it was as simple as right click project -> rename.

Is there a way to rename a Gradle project? (Without causing issues with the classes therein)

Comment: As far as I know there isn't.  You can't use the rename tool under refactor on the projects.

Answer (score 2):

1. Access the `build.gradle` file and you can change project file name to be `name = 'newName'`
2. Access the `settings.gradle` and change rootProject.name as `rootProject.name = 'NewName'`
3. Then try checking the name changed by running `$ gradle -r | grep name`

Answer (score 1):

edit settings.gradle file:

```
 rootProject.name = 'newNameHere'
```

then right click ( on the project gradle icon ) > Reload Project

**NOTE: if you have errors in your config or files name wont be changed**

Answer (score 0):

My `settings.gradle` had only one line and the `build.gradle` didn't have a `name` parameter, so this is what I did:

1. Changed `rootProject.name = 'NewName'` in `settings.gradle`
2. Refactored the main class name (the class that contains main()) to the new name `public class NewName`.
3. Changed to the new name, the manifest attributes and mainClass values in `build.gradle`:

   manifest {
       attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.abc.NewName'
   }

and

```
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'com.abc.NewName'
}
```